# How can I compile Vim without requiring libsodium?

Tags: installing, compile-vim

I have a limited OS, and compiling vim. How to disable libsodium lib?

I installed `libsodium18` and `libsodium-dev` and `libsodium-dbg`, but I get the following errors:

```
error: 'crypto_pwhash_argon2id_SALTBYTES' undeclared here (not in function)
```

Comment: Probably configure without sodium or edit the makefile

Comment: Can you provide more information? What version is libsodium-dev? How do you compile (e.g. what configure flags did you use)? Can you show a logfile of configure and compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring vim before building, disable libsodium

```
./configure   ...    --disable-libsodium    ...
```